# How do i specify the width of a ggplot2 colourbar to be half the width of the panel?

Tags: r, ggplot2

With ggplot2, is there a way to specify a colourbar width which is scaled relative to the size of the plot panel?

i.e. what can be supplied to legend.key.width such that the relative width of the key is kept the same regardless of the size of the plot?

```r
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key.width = unit(0.1, "npc")) # not relative

# or could it be done with a custom theme?
my_theme <- function() {
  theme_bw() %+replace%
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", ?)

ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  my_theme()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query the device size and change the `legend.key.width` accordingly. So your `my_theme` function could be:

```r
my_theme <- function() {
  theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
          legend.key.width = unit(dev.size()[1] / 10, "inches"))
}
```

So now when we do:

```r
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  my_theme()
```

We get:

[image]

But if we narrow the plot down **and call the above code again** we get

[image]

Or if we make it very wide and call it again we get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works wonderfully,
Why does a half width bar require dividing the width of the device by 10, and not 2?

Comment: @BetaScoo8 I don't know why this happens. `dev.size()` is supposed to be in inches, and we are specifying "inches" in the `unit` call so dividing it by two should work. I'm not sure if this perhaps is something internal to the way grob size is calculated in `ggplot`